# This keeps copying row11 instead or row2 please help Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is what I have so far, I'm trying to get this so the newest logs are at the top of LogBook but the copy function isn't working as intended. please help.

Example Below:(Note row1 is a header)

```
function Example() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rr1 = spreadsheet.getRange('A2:C2')
  var rr2 = spreadsheet.getRange('H2')
  spreadsheet.getRangeList(['A2:C2', 'H2']).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('LogBook'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('2:2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C2').activate();
  rr1.copyto('C2:E2')
  rr2.copyTo('F2')
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  var date = new Date();
  date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setValue(date);
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2').activate();
  date = new Date();
  date.setFullYear(1899, 11, 30);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setValue(date)
  .setNumberFormat('h:mm:ss am/pm');
};
```

Comment: I didn't replicate, but your problem is probably coming from the insertRowsBefore. If you getRange and then add row, the first value is unchanged. If your problem persist, you should join image of your spreadsheet

Comment: Kindly include a sample spreadsheet or at least screenshots of the data.